# How to style the NSString using CSS?

Tags: css, objective-c, nsstring

I have a dictionary project using database. I want to style the result so that it can be separated lines, have difference colors etc.

Example:

> **Song**  ///this line will be blue color with strong text
>   **N.**    // this line will be black color with strong text
>   うた       // this line will be normal gray color

It hard to put each into label in Objective-C. I wonder is it possible to style with CSS?

Comment: What about NSAttributedString?

Comment: NSAttributedString, UIWebView?

Comment: Oh as long as I have nothing to do with web, I do not use UIWebview.

Comment: I'm not even sure you need a UIWebView...  NSAttributedString's initWithHtml should get it done - you can use a UILabel's attributedText property

Comment: Do you have some tutorials to show me how ?

Comment: Use NSAttributedString, see an example in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
NSString *htmlTemplate = 
    @"<html>\n"
    "<head>\n"
    "<style type=\"text/css\">\n"
        "h4 {\n"
        "text-transform: uppercase;\n"
        "margin-bottom: 5px;\n"
        "font-family: HelveticaNeue;\n"
        "font-size: 18px;\n"
        "color: #212121;\n"
        "font-weight: bold;\n"
        "line-height: 1.1;\n"
        "text-align: center;\n"
        "margin-bottom: 15px\n"
    "}\n"
    "p {\n"
        "text-align: center;\n"
        "color: #757575;\n"
        "line-height: 1.2;\n"
        "font-family: Helvetica;\n"
        "font-size: 18px;\n"
    "}\n"
    "</style>\n"
    "</head>\n"
    "<body>\n"
    "%@\n"
    "</body>\n"
    "</html>";

NSString *text = @"<h4>This is a test</h4><p>Testing CSS styled text with Objective-C</p>";

myLabel.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                            initWithData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:htmlTemplate, text] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                            options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType }
                            documentAttributes:nil
                            error:nil];
```

This is just an example to get you going, you can add more HTML and line breaks to the template as you see fit.

Comment: Hi thanks for this, lookig interesting. But should I use it with UIwebView or not ?

Comment: No, use it with any UILabel object.

Comment: You are cool !  Almost there--->I got error message says :property "attributedText" not found on object of type "NSSString"

Comment: Make sure you are setting "attributedText" on a "UILabel" object. It sounds like you're setting it on an "NSString" object instead.

Comment: You are incredable !! Juan
--> I wonder how about ErasmoOliveira  who said this is impossible and will close my question->where are you ? can you please look at this ?
OMG, he is gone !! Bad people not enough education will always be rude--->good people keep calm and give resolution !! I can see

Comment: One more, Juan---> Can you give example to me if I want to color the text outside the h4 tag ? I don´t know how to eppend this to your code.

Comment: I used "h4" and "p" in my example but you can apply the same principle to any HTML tag, just as you would in a web page. Try adding something like "body { text-color: #ff0000; }" in the CSS definition part.

Comment: I need help with this. I can not use some css properties with this answer. eg. ---> display:inline; margin-left:50px;   seems like we can not set margin and padding if we use display:inline or inline-block. anyway to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Display your content in a `UIWebView` and make use of a bundled CSS file.

Comment: Oh, I have nothing to do with web, I can not use this method.
I think I need to put more column in database to display it in its label in objective-c :(